# How to remove elements from my application window?

Tags: javascript, http, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to remove an existed button when i click on it... this is what i'm looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/4WGRP/  but when i tried to do that using Samsung smart TV application...its giving me an Error!!!!! :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'remove'
```

seems that Remove method is not defined,, SO how removing works in Samsung smart TV application!!! 
please can somebody help me!!! any hint will help!! Thanks

html code:

```
     <div id= "menu_list1"  >
    <h3>Choose a litter to begin</h3>
    <div class= "hello" >
        <a href="#openModal"  onkeydown="Main.keyDown();">A</a></div>
        <div id="openModal"  class="modalDialog"><div>
    <a href="#close" id='btn' class="Close">Back</a></div>
    </div>
```

javaScript code:

```
case tvKey.KEY_UP:
    alert("UP");
    $('.modalDialog').eq(current_selected_index).removeClass('modalDialog');
    this.remove();
break;
```

Note: modalDialog its like a pop-up window contain a button could Back when i press this button the button and this pop up should remove ... the pop-up removed correctly using (removeClass) but the button doesn't!!! this is the problem!!

Comment: remove() is a JQuery method you should include <script src=http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js></script> to your code. In pure javascript you have elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem) (needs parent element)

Comment: i did this include and i have the JQuery file with my .Java file in the main project folder...So now should i create parent which is the main elements and a child which is what i wanna delete ??

Comment: Please put your code so we can see where's the problem

Comment: ok i already added my code @radia can you chick it please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i just Replaced:

```
this.remove();
```

By:

```
$( '.Close' ).remove();
```

and its worked,, the button disappeared!!!
thanx guys!!

Comment: A better solution will be to use $(this) instead of $('.Close').